# One Comcast Business Gateway, One Router, Two Web Servers

Tags: subnet, nic, domain

I have a Comcast business account with a router and a web server (info) attached.  behind the router there are multiple computers and a second web server (info) which also serves as a file server.

(info) has two nics in it.  One direct to comcast and one connected to the router.   It needs to serve the world it's websites.  It needs however, to also be able to see all the internal computers and (com)'s served files.

With just 1 nic (the one connected to the router, not comcast), (info) works fine but no one outside can see it.  (com) services port 80 and (info) needs to handle port 80 as well.  I have two domain names registered, and 5 static ip's from comcast.

right now `http://www.graceamazing.com` handled by (com) works fine and `http:/ /www.graceamazing.com:1307` handled by (info) works fine.  but as soon as I enable the 2nd nic in (info) `http://www.graceamazing.info` runs extremely slow (Horribly slow).  however, `http://www.graceamazing.com:1307` and .com work fine.

(com) has an ip address via the router
70.89.233.41

(info) has a ip addy of 70.89.233.46 via comcast (2nd nic) and a internal ip of 192.168.x.100 via static behind the router.

Any suggestions or changes to make that will make `http://www.graceamazing.info` perform with the same speed it has when going through `http://graceamazing.com:1307`?

is there a setting I should check / could have misssed?

Comment: My suspicion is that this boils down to a default gateway issue...you can't have more than one default gateway on a multihomed server.  Having said that, your text "diagram" is very hard to follow, but it sounds like you have the router *behind* the server instead of in front of it?

Answer (score 1):

Greg is probably onto something. Did you check your routing tables on the servers before and after? You may need to add routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup sounds more complicated than it needs to be.  Can you not just put both servers behind the router/firewall, then configure both wan IPs on the router's wan interface and forward port 80 for each wan IP to its respective server?